# xml parse error no element found while using JSON?

Tags: json, ajax, xml

I'm using JSON to put data in my database, but while using POST I get

```
XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal:{7c3ebd98-a00f-4a72-8a89-8094946cef8e Line Number 1, Column 1:
```

The browser gets the correct JSON file, but I still get the error:

```
    function comment() {
        if ($.trim($("textarea#inputdefault").val()) != "") {
            var reacties = $("textarea#inputdefault").val();
            var reactie = {
                reactieId: 2,
                Datum: "2016-05-25 01:20:54.843",
                Inhoud: $("textarea#inputdefault").val(),
                voorstelId: voorstelID

            }
            postAjaxCall(commentUri, reactie);
            console.log("Input: " + reactie);
            console.log("commentUri: " + commentUri);
            console.log("voorstelID: " + voorstelID);
            console.log("voorstelID: " + voorstelID);


            $('textarea#inputdefault').val('')
        } else {
            alert("Vul iets in!");
        }
    }

    function postAjaxCall(commentUri, comment) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: commentUri,
            data: JSON.stringify(comment),
            contentType: 'application/json'
        }).success(function (data) {
            console.log("URL: " + commentUri);
            console.log("data: " + JSON.stringify(comment));

        })
    }
```

I'm can't find my fault, and already lost hours

Comment: What is producing this error?  Maybe the service you are calling is expecting it to be XML and ignoring your contentType?

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a typo; I'm on mobile so I can't see line numbers, but near the bottom in your Ajax call, you have "url: commentUri"; did you intend to say "commentUrl"?

Edit: never mind, I see now that was intentional.